# Get product locations from Uber developer API

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates, uber-api

Is it possible to retrieve all the current locations of the products within a certain area ? I would like to display them live on a gmap the exact same way the official Uber app does it.
There's no such information in their API.

Bests

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Uber hasn't provided such API, the only thing you can do is get the closest product in each kind such as People's Uber, UberXL, Uber Black and UberX.
And you can request an estimate for each kind of product and Uber would return the response including driver info and car info.